# Alternative for UrlEncodedFormEntity for sending data via POST

Tags: android, json, web-services, post

When sending the POST request using UrlEncodedFormEntity which takes List as input parameter along with the key, my request gets converted in the form of `[key={json}]` .

But the request i want to send should be in the form of `key={json}` , i.e not as List.

So, is there any alternative for the given method when using POST?

**notes:** webservice is working fine , and since it is json ,i cannot use Soap .

i ve tested it using POSTman and webservices are WCF(if thats of any use..)

if any code is required , please mention it.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit** code:

```
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL); 
            List<NameValuePair> value=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",string)); 

            //here it passes as List and here is where i want an alternate method 
            // by which i can send parameter as JSONobject
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);                
            request.setEntity(entity); 

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity2 = response.getEntity();
            if(entity2.getContentLength() != 0) {
                Reader tapReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());               
                char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];              
                tapReader.read(buffer);          
                tapReader.close();                                                                                           
                JSONObject tapJsonObj =  new JSONObject(buffer);
```

Comment: post the respective code

Comment: in short - method like UrlEncodedFormEntity but passes parameter as JSONobject and not as List.